# Есть несколько локальных ПК, как один из них сделать веб - сервером для других?

Tags: сервер

Как поднять сервер я знаю, но как все настроить? (выхода в интернет нет) Как ip прописывать и пр. ?

Comment: Насколько я знаю, если Вы поставили Apache, то после его установки, вы сразу же сможете соединятся со своим сервером по локальное сети

Comment: Вам надо все серьёзно с днс и прочим? Или хотите по пути наименьшего сопротивления?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

А зачем он там нужен? Выход в интернет? Если Вам нужно, чтобы работало локально. Нужно только заранее скачать ПО веб-сервера. Тот же nginx или Apache или что Вы там больше любите и можете настроить, как Вы пишете.

Если говорите установить веб-сервер можете, то вопроса настройке нет и вовсе. У компьютера есть же IP-адрес? Обращаетесь тогда к нему так http://ай-пи-адрес-этого-внутреннего-сервера.

Хотите по имени? Самое простое - на ВСЕХ клиентских машинах внести имя и адрес этого сервера в файл /etc/hosts или /Windows/System32/drivers/etc/hosts

А если Вы под Windows и этот компьютер уже виден по сети прочим компьютерам по имени, то и настраивать ничего не надо.

Для менее ручной настройки (чтобы не бегать по всем компьютерам и не править hosts) необходимо внести запись (с именем и адресом вашего веб-сервера) в DNS. Если его у Вас нет, то его нужно поднять. Но, может, достаточно и hosts поправить?